# How to fix background gradiend on resize Chart.js / canvas

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, canvas, charts

I am using the react chart js for displaying Line chart.

My gradient background is broken on resize window screen, it becomes black:

[image]

How to make it work by changing the size of the screen?

This is the function that creates and generates a gradient:

```
export const getGradientBackground = (canvas) => {
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(
        canvas.width / 2,
        0,
        canvas.width / 2,
        canvas.height
    );

    gradient.addColorStop(0.1, 'rgba(0, 145, 148, 0.15)');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.2, 'rgba(0, 145, 148, 0.15)');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.3, 'rgba(0, 145, 148, 0.15)');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.4, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.5, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.6, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.7, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.8, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)');
    gradient.addColorStop(0.9, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)');
    gradient.addColorStop(1.0, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)');

    ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 200, 100);

    return gradient;
};
```

Any comment is welcome

Comment: If you have a reproducible example like a stackblitz or something it's likely an easy remedy but seeing the issue in an example to troubleshoot from would go a long way. I assume it's your `fillRect` declaration that's the culprit wherein you could be instead using the `chartArea` interface [like this](https://dev.to/ricnish/chartjs-with-gradient-background-5fai)

Comment: are you using this package? https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2

Comment: Hi @MarkJames, similar to Chris's request, it would be very helpful to see a live working example of this that we can tinker with to get working, to ensure we provide a true working solution to the issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I followed the link provided by [Chris W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1090206/chris-w) in the comment and implemented it with `react-chartjs-2`

```
...
      <Line
        type="line"
        data={data}
        options={options}
        plugins={[
          {
            beforeDraw: function (chart, args, options) {
              const ctx = chart.ctx;
              const canvas = chart.canvas;
              const chartArea = chart.chartArea;

              // Chart background
              var gradient = canvas
                .getContext("2d")
                .createLinearGradient(
                  canvas.width / 2,
                  0,
                  canvas.width / 2,
                  canvas.height
                );
              gradient.addColorStop(0.1, "rgba(0, 145, 148, 0.15)");
              gradient.addColorStop(0.2, "rgba(0, 145, 148, 0.15)");
              gradient.addColorStop(0.3, "rgba(0, 145, 148, 0.15)");
              gradient.addColorStop(0.4, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)");
              gradient.addColorStop(0.5, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)");
              gradient.addColorStop(0.6, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)");
              gradient.addColorStop(0.7, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)");
              gradient.addColorStop(0.8, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)");
              gradient.addColorStop(0.9, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)");
              gradient.addColorStop(1.0, "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15)");

              ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
              ctx.fillRect(
                chartArea.left,
                chartArea.bottom,
                chartArea.right - chartArea.left,
                chartArea.top - chartArea.bottom
              );
            }
          }
        ]}
      />
...
```

As you can see in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/chart-js-background-h2lj5?file=/src/App.tsx), the background persists when you resize the screen. Probably the problem was that you were not taking into account the chart dimensions to calculate background rectangle dimensions

Comment: The "250" in createLinearGradient needs to be changed if you want it to stay relative to the canvas' size.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when I was using apexcharts.js(similar to Chart.js) I had to add background color to y-axis for that I used SVG(you can also do the same with canvas).

Due to appending an svg element dynamically or drawing a canvas if the window is resized it would make that element disappeared, for that I used resize event which would fire a function after 500ms to re-add that element.

This counter of 500 ms gets restarted whenever there is a change in the window's dimensions (as we clear the timeout) so the function will only be called if the user stops resizing the window or if the user resizes the window VERY slowly which doesn't happens normally.

#### This will work for you

```
var func;

window.addEventListener("resize", function(){
  clearTimeout(func);
func = setTimeout(getGradientBackground, 500);
})
```